# Novice to code: Converting individual numbers from an input into seperate values in binary

Tags: python, binary

So I'm a first year student and I have an assignment asking me to write a program that takes a user input, (in this case, my student ID) converts each number into binary and then checks to see if it's the correct ID, if it is it lights a greed LED.

I know how to input the ID, I know how to check if it's correct and I know how to light the LED.

Basically what I'm after is

```
id = input
id = list(id)
```

Then I need to convert each number in the list to binary, so for example `[1,2,3,4]` to `[0001,0010,0011,0010]` then

```
  if id[0] ==binary_1:
   print ("correct")
   light green LED
  else:
   print ("incorrect")
   light red LED
```

What I have no clue how to tackle is how to split the input into individual numbers and then convert those into binary. Google has either yielded little results and `bin` doesn't do what I need it to.

Any ideas or help would really be appreciated. I'm at a complete loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a list comprehension to apply the conversion to binary

```
ids = [1,2,3,4]

bins = ['{0:04b}'.format(i) for i in ids]

print(bins)

['0001', '0010', '0011', '0100']
```

This would give you the binary numbers as strings e.g `'0001'` which isn't really binary in python but should be exactly what you want

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Read the input in as a string so it's iterable. Then convert each number to integer, and then binary so you can do the evaluation:

```
id = str(input())
binary_ints = [bin(int(num)) for num in id]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`binlist=[int(bin(i)[2:]) for i in id]`

This is called a *list comprehension*, you will iterate on each element of list id, apply the wanted changes to the element and append it to binlist.